# Parity of XYZ model ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, spin-models, integrable-systems, spin-chains

I am considering the XYZ Hamiltonian (with PBC) $$\widehat{H}_{\mathrm{XYZ}}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(\hat{\sigma}_{i}^{x} \hat{\sigma}_{i+1}^{x}+J_{y}\hat{\sigma}_{i}^{y} \hat{\sigma}_{i+1}^{y}+J_{z}\hat{\sigma}_{i}^{z} \hat{\sigma}_{i+1}^{z}\ \right)$$ where $J_{y}, J_{z} > 0$ and $N$ is finite and even.

For different values of $J_{y}, J_{z}$ and (even) $N$, it turns out numerically that the ground state $|{GS}\rangle$ of the XYZ Hamiltonian is such that $$\hat{P}|{GS}\rangle=\prod_{i=1}^N \hat{\sigma}_i^{x}|{GS}\rangle=(-1)^{N/2}|{GS}\rangle$$ and the ground state energy is not degenerate. How can I show it analytically?

Note that the XYZ Hamiltonian commutes with $\hat{P}$, therefore a common eigenstates basis exists. Hence, if the ground state energy is not degenerate, the ground state has to be eigenstate of $\hat{P}$ which has eigenvalues  $\pm 1$.

I would like to ask the same question about ground state degeneracy and parity also for the TFIM model (with PBC) $$\widehat{H}_{\mathrm{TFIM}}=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left(-\hat{\sigma}_{i}^{z} \hat{\sigma}_{i+1}^{z} - g \hat{\sigma}_{i}^{x} \right)$$ where $g> 0$ and $N$ is finite. In this case it turns out numerically that $\hat{P}|{GS}\rangle=|{GS}\rangle$. How can I prove it analytically?

Comment: The second equation you wrote must be wrong, it suggests that the eigenvalue of $P$ is $\pm i$ for $N$ odd.

Comment: I am not considering $N$ odd, but only $N$ EVEN as I wrote in the post.

Comment: You want to prove the absence of spontaneous breaking of $\widehat{P}$-symmetry? For finite $N$, the $\widehat{P}$-symmetry of the Hamiltonian \emph{always} translates to a $\widehat{P}$-symmetry of the ground state. So your question would be to show that the ground state is unique, and the gap is bounded in the thermodynamic limit?

Comment: My main question is about understanding if it is true that, for each $J_x, J_y>0$ and even $N$, the ground state of XYZ model is such that: $$\hat{P}|{GS}\rangle=\prod_{i=1}^N \hat{\sigma}_i^{x}|{GS}\rangle=(-1)^{N/2}|{GS}\rangle$$. But it would be nice also to have a proof of the fact that the ground state is unique for finite N.